# Exporting to excel issue in exporting number field

Tags: c#

I have one grid which contain phone numbers..and whike am exporting to it phone number field is automatically taken as numeric field and phone number is displayed as exponential.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code snippet after the workbook has been created:

```
wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("B:B").NumberFormat = "@";
```

Beware: This solution has not been tested by the author.